# Check to see if a folder is done being copied too

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, shared-directory

I want to a run a script that executes a specific program on windows that uses a bunch of files (for example a bunch of .pdf's). The problem is that I am receiving these files from another location to a shared folder. So I need to check this shared folder and execute the program only when all files have finished copying from another drive that I don't control.

Anyway to do this? All my searching has brought me to using powershell and a script like this except instead of my action logging the file, I need to execute the program but I don't know how to do that for the last copied file/folder is done growing.

```
 ### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\monitor_this"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                Add-content "C:\Users\User\Desktop\log.txt" -value   $logline
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Comment: Use a sliding timer technique: reset a timer inside $action code to a new time (5 seconds, for example) so that it'll actually execute when nothing was modifed during 5 seconds.

Comment: so I have added $timer.Interval = 20000  in the action before the add-content. But how do I get the add-content or any other part to execute once the timer has run out?

Comment: add-content should be inside timer's `action`

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments of wOxxOm I tried to extend above example:

```html
 ### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\monitor_this"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### Create timer
    $timer = new-object timers.timer 
    $timer.Interval = 5000 #5 seconds
    $timer.Enabled = $true

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
   $fileWatcherAction = {
       # Reset the timer every time the file watcher reports a change
       write-host "Timer Elapse Event: $(get-date -Format ‘HH:mm:ss’)"
       $timer.Stop()
       $timer.Start()
   } 

    $timerAction = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                Add-content "C:\Users\User\Desktop\log.txt" -value   $logline
              }    

### When timer fires timerAction is called
    Register-ObjectEvent $timer "Elapsed" -Action $timerAction

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED, every call of below events resets the timer
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $fileWatcherAction
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $fileWatcherAction
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $fileWatcherAction
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $fileWatcherAction
    while ($true) {Start-Sleep 5}
```

What I'm actually not sure about is the closure handling of `$timer`, maybe you've to do some additional research about Powershell and closures.

Hope that helps.